# How can I remove all attributes of p elements in HTML files using Perl?

Tags: html, regex, perl, command-line

I'd like to remove all attributes of `<p>` in an HTML file by using this simple Perl command line:

```
$ perl -pe 's/<p[^>]*>/<p>/' input.html
```

However, it won't substitute e.g. `<p class="hello">` that spans multiple lines such as

```
<p 
class="hello">
```

Thus, I attempted to first remove the end of line by doing

```
# command-1
$ perl -pe 's/\n/ /' input.html > input-tmp.html
# command-2
$ perl -pe 's/<p[^>]*>/<p>/g' input-tmp.html > input-final.html
```

Questions:

1. Is there an option in (Perl) regex to try the match across multiple lines?
2. Can I combine the two commands above (*command-1* and *command-2*) into one? Basically, the first command needs to complete execution before the second one starts.

Comment: What about `<pre>`? Allow me to draw your attention to [this enlightning answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)...

Comment: @ikegami: I was trying to remove all the attributes of `<p>`, not the tag / element itself.

Comment: @Johnsyweb: Thank you for pointing that post. I was using regex to clean up some HTML files, not to necessarily "parse" it -- I am glad!

Comment: If you do not parse the HTML to clean it up, you might end up making a **clbuttic** mistake.

Comment: @Siku-Siku.Com, ah yes. Comment retracted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`-p` is short for

```
LINE: while (<>) {
   ...
} continue {
   print
      or die "-p destination: $!\n";
}
```

As you can see `$_` only contains one line at a times, so the pattern can't possibly match something that spans more than one line. You can fool Perl into thinking the whole file is one line using `-0777`.

```
perl -0777 -pe's/<p[^>]*>/<p>/g' input.html
```

Command line options are documented in [perlrun](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html).

Answer (score 1):

If you write a short script, and put it in its own file, you can easily invoke it using a simple command line.

Improving the following script is left as an exercise:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings; use strict;
use HTML::TokeParser::Simple;

run(\@ARGV);

sub run {
    my ($argv, $opt) = @_;

    my $el = shift @$argv;

    for my $src (@$argv) {
        clean_attribs($src, $el, $opt);
    }
}

sub clean_attribs {
    my ($src, $el, $opt) = @_;
    my $el_pat = qr/^$el\z/;

    my $parser = HTML::TokeParser::Simple->new($src, %$opt);

    while (my $token = $parser->get_token) {
        if ($token->is_start_tag($el_pat)) {
            my $tag = $token->get_tag;
            print "<$tag>";
        }
        else {
            print $token->as_is;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`perl -pe 'undef $/; s/<p[^>]*>/<p>/g'`

Answer (score -3):

```
$ perl -pe 's/\n/ /; s/<p[^>]*>/<p>/gs;' input.html > input-final.html
```

Comment: There's no `.` for `s` to affect. It doesn't help. Furthermore, joining the two commands in this fashion caused the commands to stop working.

Comment: Unfortunately, when you combined those two commands as suggested, the `<p>` substitution doesn't work across multiple lines even with the 's' added. I think it's because the first command and the second are in the same loop. As mentioned in the question, I think the first command needs to finish execution before the second should start.