# Remove HTML Tags From A String, Using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a simple string e.g.

```
var s = "<p>Hello World!</p><p>By Mars</p>";
```

How do I convert `s` to a jQuery object? My objective is to remove the `<p>`s and `</p>`s. I could have done this using regex, but that's rather [not recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7886634/583539).

Comment: You just should have read the documentation a bit better: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2

Comment: @hippietrail: The latter. The accepted answer i.e. `.text()` does fulfill what I needed.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the simplest form (if I am understanding correctly):

```
var s = "<p>Hello World!</p><p>By Mars</p>";
var o = $(s);
var text = o.text();
```

Or you could use a conditional selector with a search context:

```
// load string as object, wrapped in an outer container to use for search context
var o = $("<div><p>Hello World!</p><p>By Mars</p></div>");

// sets the context to only look within o; otherwise, this will return all P tags
var tags = $("P", o); 

tags.each(function(){
    var tag = $(this); // get a jQuery object for the tag
    // do something with the contents of the tag
});
```

If you are parsing large amounts of HTML (for example, interpreting the results of a screen scrape), use a server-side HTML parsing library, not jQuery (tons of posts on here about HTML parsing).

Comment: `$("P", o);` would not work though. It's the same as `o.find('p')`, meaning it looks for `p`-descendants of the selected elements. But the selected elements are already the `p` elements.

Comment: @FelixKling - you are absolutely right...I shouldn't write code at 2am. I will update my example, because I think a contextual selector is a useful option to have.

Answer (score 1):

To get all the strings there use

```
var s = "<p>Hello World!</p><p>By Mars</p>";
var result = "";
$.each($(s), function(i){
    result += " " + $(this).html();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

if you don't want regex, why don't u just:

```
var s = "<p>Hello World!</p><p>By Mars</p>";
s = s.replace('<p>', '').replace('</p>', '');
```

Comment: Unless that is **exactly** the expression the OP needs, a string replace will break if the tags are cased differently or there are attributes within the tag.

Comment: though it changes only the first occurence =\ I would not say that s = s.replace(/<\/?p>/i, ''); is bad

Comment: oh sure, if it comes to attribute parsing it's a simple regex also... s = s.replace(/<\/?p[^>]*>/i, '');

Comment: General consensus on SO (me included) is that using regular expressions to parse HTML is not the ideal solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags. It works in simple cases, but it is very brittle even compared to something like jQuery which uses the browser's DOM or a robust server-side parser that does a character by character parse and accounts for all the possibilities which exist in valid/invalid HTML.

Comment: yup but if you write regex for general case it's always effective, this question is too simple to suggest real char-by-char parsing solution, I truly believe...

Comment: This answer has exactly the same problem as using regex. Though I agree that if the "simple string" mentioned in the question is going to reliable follow that format then a string replace (with or without regex) would do the trick fine.

Comment: The string above is only an example (thus, using **e.g.** not **i.e.**). As mentioned in the question, I was looking for essentially a non-regex solution. Thanks for the suggestion, though.

Comment: @nnnnnn, I was talkin about any kind of <p> tag in this case, which will allow using any valid attribute, its value and an end-tag