# InnerText=InnerHtml - How to extract readable text with HtmlAgilityPack

Tags: html, vb.net, html-agility-pack, innerhtml, innertext

I need to extract text from a very bad Html.

I'm trying to do this using `vb.net` and `HtmlAgilityPack`

The tag that I need to parse has InnerText = InnerHtml and both:

```
Name:<!--b>&#61;</b--> Albert E<!--span-->instein  s<!--i>&#89;</i-->ection: 3 room: -
```

While debuging I can read it using "Html viewer": it shows:

```
Name: Albert Einstein section: 3 room: -
```

How can I get this into a string variable?

EDIT:

I use this code to get the node:

```
Dim ElePs As HtmlNodeCollection = _
    mWPage.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@id='div_main']//p")
For Each EleP As HtmlNode In ElePs
    'Here I need to get EleP.InnerText "normalized"
Next
```

Comment: can you tried this ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3442394/jquery-using-text-to-retrieve-only-text-not-nested-in-child-tags i don't know if that work on bad html...try

Comment: You need to post more of the html I think - it doesn't look that bad on the face of it

Comment: @Mr.Developer Can you explain a little more? I understood the logic but I need more hel to try it. Thanks in advance

Comment: i have try another question here on stavkover...try the solution..if work also on bad html

Comment: this remove all tags...also bad tags...try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8692423/remove-html-tags-from-a-string-using-jquery

Comment: @Mr.Developer I'm using vb.net (and I'm not a pro) if it's possible to use the Jquery functions in vb.net I don't know how to. I'm parsing the page using HtmlAgilityPack

Comment: I do not know if you can , but if you change the question people might find that it helps you

Comment: @MattWilko I added the full tag code (I hope is what you were asking for)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you notice this mess is actually just html comments and they shall be ignored, so just getting the text and using `string.Join` is enough:

C#

```
var text = string.Join("",htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//text()[normalize-space()]").
                                            Select(t=>t.InnerText));
```

VB.net

```
 Dim text = String.Join("", From t In htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//text()[normalize-space()]")
                                   Select t.InnerText)
```

the html is valid, nothing bad about it, its just written by someone without a soul.

**based on your update this shall do:**

```
Dim ElePs As HtmlNodeCollection = mWPage.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@id='div_main']//p")
For Each EleP As HtmlNode In ElePs
    'Here I need to get EleP.InnerText "normalized"
     Dim text = String.Join("", From t In EleP.SelectNodes(".//text()[normalize-space()]")
                Select t.InnerText).Trim()
Next
```

note the `.//` it means that it will look for the descendant nodes of the current node unlike `//` which will always start from the top node.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I wasn't able to adapt it to my code. I updated my question to show how I get the Html Element which I need to extract InnerText. Can you please adapt your answer to my code?