# Normalize string from HtmlAgilityPack document

Tags: vb.net, string, html-agility-pack

I'm trying to get a web page using `vb.net` and `HtmlAgilityPack` with this code:

```
Dim mWPage As New HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument
Dim wC As New WebClient()
mWPage.Load(wC.OpenRead(mUrl))
```

My problem is to get text from a table but, when I extract InnerText, i get something like this:

```
&#77;o&#100;if&#105;ca&#116;<!--span-->i&#32; da&#116;i
```

instead of (Note that I wrote the same string and below it's displayed correctly):

> Modificati  dati

I've tryed to use the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35744250/innertext-innerhtml-how-to-extract-readable-text-with-htmlagilitypack/35753228?s=1%7C0.1254#35753228) but it doesn't work in this case (or I wasn't able to make it works)

I noticed that contents changes when I change "User-Agent", so I tryed various "User-Agent" but I never got a perfect text.

So my questions are:
can I use the code that is indicated in the answer to solve the problem?
if not, can I get a perfect text using the right  "User-Agent"?
If so, how can I find the right  "User-Agent"?
If not, how can I fix the receivedstring?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The response from the server based on a new User-Agent is fully dependent on the server so we will not be able to predict which one will yield the response you're looking for.

But... You will be able to use the [`HttpUtility.HtmlDecode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.htmldecode(v=vs.110).aspx) method to get rid of the encoded HTML and turn it into teh string you're looking for.

To filter out the HTML comment you may need to change the XPath you're using. If you append `//text()`, you should get only the text elements that match the rest of your expression.

Comment: Thanks for helping. In any case I had to change `HttpUtility.HtmlDecode` with `WebUtility.HtmlDecode`